# How can I change directory of AnkiDroid to external Storage

Tags: ankidroid

After using anki for a while , my internal storage (16gigs)became full, and now I'm unable to add more cards, then I tried to change directory to external Storage but it did not work for me (I'm using Android 7.1.1 moto g4 play) and ot keeps popping up message saying 'the given path isn't valid' .if someone could help me out it would be great

Comment: What do you mean by "ot"? Is it a typo maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to store an app on your memory card could be using a card formatted in "Portable storage" mode. In that case no one single app can be pushed out of internal memory, but reformatting of a memory card in "Internal storage" mode can change that. Another reason could be a restriction made by app's developer and there is nothing a user can do about it.
Sources: https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-format-microsd-cards-as-internal-storage
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html